# TypeScript not following logic

Tags: typescript

```
const PACT_TAGS: string[] = [];

const CI_BRANCH: string | undefined = process.env.CI_BRANCH;
const CI_USER: string | undefined = process.env.CI_USER;
const CI_COMMIT: string | undefined = process.env.CI_COMMIT;

const isCiPipeline = CI_BRANCH !== undefined && CI_USER !== undefined && CI_COMMIT !== undefined;

if (isCiPipeline) {
    PACT_TAGS.push(CI_COMMIT); // <- error
    PACT_TAGS.push(CI_BRANCH); // <- error
    PACT_TAGS.push(CI_USER); // <- error
}
```

The error is:

```
const CI_COMMIT: string | undefined
Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)
```

I think you can figure out what I'm trying to do here. Those three lines in the if clause can only be hit if those three types are of type string. I could write `<string>` and cast them but then what is the point of TypeScript.

Comment: If you inline `isCiPipeline`, the types get narrowed to `string` as you expect. But when you extract to a boolean it's *just* a boolean, the types don't get narrowed.

Comment: If `PACT_TAGS` is defined as `string[]`, then of course you get errors. The type of `string` is not the same as `string | undefined`. Either you change the constant types, or use and intermediate step when pushing them to the array.

Comment: @RomiHalasz it is of type string[]. I updated the question with this info.

Answer (score 0):

Like what @jonrsharpe has suggested, `isCiPipeline`  is a boolean and it does not help to narrow the types of your constants down so that TypeScript only see them as `string` instead of `string | undefined`.

One of the suggestion is to inline the `undefined` checks, i.e.:

```
if (CI_BRANCH !== undefined && CI_USER !== undefined && CI_COMMIT !== undefined) {
  PACT_TAGS.push(CI_COMMIT);
  PACT_TAGS.push(CI_BRANCH);
  PACT_TAGS.push(CI_USER);
}
```

In this case, TypeScript can directly infer from the if statement that none of your constants can possibly be a type of `undefined` and can only be `string`.

Alternatively, if you really know what you're doing, you can also tell TypeScript that you are sure the constants are not undefined by using the [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator):

```
if (isCiPipeline) {
  PACT_TAGS.push(CI_COMMIT!);
  PACT_TAGS.push(CI_BRANCH!);
  PACT_TAGS.push(CI_USER!);
}
```